# Increment adding to disk by smaller chunks until whole PDF is generated

Tags: itext

We are creating more than 20,000 pages using iText.

Write now the application crashes with out of memory exception.

I heard some of the PDF writers will write smaller chunks to disk and finally completes the PDF and doesn't throw out of memory exception.

Is that true? What would be the best way to write PDF in text without leading to Out Of Memory Exception ? FileOutPutStream/ByteArrayOutputStream/Pipe..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PdfWriter`, if used correctly, writes stuff as early as possible to the output stream. Obviously wrong e.g. is to build gigantic tables in memory and add them to the document all at once when finished. Obviously wrong also is to use a `PdfWriter` writing into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` for big PDFs unless you have huge amounts of memory.

Comment: @Kathiresa: are you creating one big `PdfPTable` and then, when the table is finished, adding it to the `Document` as mkl is guessing? I'm voting to close this question as "too broad" because you don't show any code. When used correctly, iText writes small chunks to the disks and frees up memory. Based on your question, we can only assume that you're not using iText correctly, but apparently you don't want people to see your code out of fear that they would show you that your code is wrong.